# How to capture a portion of screen?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot, screen-capture

I just want to know how to capture a portion of the screen. Getting the screen shot of a particular location and size in Windows.

I want to do this using some Windows key functionality. I am not doing using and code, I am not looking for any tool. I just want to know either this is possible in Windows or not.

Comment: Do you want to do it programatically? From which language/environment? What sort of screen capture? There are many possible duplicates (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043880/net-browser-screen-capture-utility for .Net)

Comment: FYI :if it was in any language i would have tagged it
Still i have clarified it in my edited version of question

Comment: some thing like select a part of screen using mouse and capture only that portion

Comment: This is not a programming related question, which will most likely be closed soon,  but Windows Vista and Windows 7 has a program called "Snipping Tool" that can do that.

Comment: You might also want to ask this on superuser instead of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

Capture it with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrnScr</kbd> (so it gets only the active window) and then crop it in a program of your choice.

Answer (score 3):

The [snipping tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/snipping-tool) is a utility provided by default in Windows 7 and above.
It does what you requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a program that gets a handle to the screen's device context (`GetDC`), does a `BitBlt` from that device context to a temporary one you created with `CreateCompatibleDC` and populated with `CreateCompatibleBitmap`.  Then you select your memory bitmap out and save it.  Make sure to release and destroy these GDI resources.

Do do this when the user hits a certain key, your program should call `RegisterHotKey` and then wait for the notification.

Search MSDN for these function names for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 you just need <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and then select the region you want to capture

Another new shortcut is <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>: Save the desktop as a file in the Pictures folder instead of copying to clipboard

There's also a new tool called *Snip & Sketch* to capture the screen. It may replace `Snipping tool` in the future